# How to use awk inside C-shell alias?

Tags: linux, awk, csh

I am adding an alias in C-Shell terminal as below

```
alias rs1 "p | grep -i 'container 1' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
```

Once the alias is added I can see alias is added as

```
rs1  p | grep -i 'container 1' | awk '{print }' | xargs kill -9
```

Where I can see `$2` is not present inside awk.

I also tried using `awk "{print $2}"` But using double quote inside awk is not working in suse12.
Any idea to solve this?

Comment: It looks like the trivial fix would be to backslash the dollar signs. If that doesn't help, switching to a sane shell would be my recommendation.

Comment: Also, [don't use `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill)

Answer (score 4):

After exploring a few ways, `$2` is escaped and enclosed by double quotes as `"\$"` it worked

```
alias rs1 "p | grep -i 'container 1' | awk '{print "\$"2}' | xargs kill -9"
```

Which give alias result as

```
rs1  p | grep -i 'container 1' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```